# I can't check simple post route, i get 405 Method Not Allowed error

Tags: laravel

simply i have this below route:

```
Route::post ('clientLoginAccount', 'AuthController@clientLoginAccount');
```

and i want to post some data as an json object or other format to that, i try to test this route by `RESTClient` addon on firefox, but i get error:

```
405 Method Not Allowed
```

`clientLoginAccount` method on `AuthController`

```
public function clientLoginAccount()
{
    echo json_encode(['test'=>' ok']);
}
```

[image]

route list:

```
| | POST|clientLoginAccount |  | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@clientLoginAccount   | web |
```

Comment: There are prefix `public` in your route? Try [http://192.168.1.35/clientLoginAccount](http://192.168.1.35/clientLoginAccount)

Comment: @huuuk yes there is `public` on my url, get method supported but, post method not

Comment: and what's about CSRF? Are you include token to your request?

Comment: @huuuk i dont have any form and i want to use this url on android webservice

Comment: What `artisan route:list` returns?

Comment: Exclude CSRF Token for that route

Comment: @xdevnull not working sir: `protected $except = ['clientLoginAccount/*',];`

Comment: According to the output of the command you should call `clientLoginAccount ` instead of `public/clientLoginAccount`

Comment: @xdevnull change `'clientLoginAccount/*'` to `'clientLoginAccount` work fine and my problem solved

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy That was my first answer

Comment: @xdevnull yes, problem was `/*` on except array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude `CSRF-Token Verficiation` for that route.

Open **VerifyCsrfToken Middleware** and add `clientLoginAccount` to the `$except` array

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    protected $except = 
        'clientLoginAccount'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must expect `405 Method Not Allowed` is very big problem when you or someone are using your `API`, you should be manage that inside controller, your problem is form method not `CSRF`. In any case you should use this solution for example:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function clientLoginAccount(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->method() != 'POST') {
            return response()->json(['data' => "Request must be 'POST'", 'status' => '1'], 200);
        }
    }
}
```